# Changing an int value in struct which is in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a struct:

```
struct person{
     char* name;
     char* surname;
     int age;
};
```

And I use this struct inside another struct for linked list:

```
struct listNode {
     struct person data;
     struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

I am trying to insert one struct into the linked list. After that I want to get this struct by index and change the age value. In main, I have these codes:

```
int main() {

    ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL;

    struct person p;

    p.age = 22;
    p.surname = "Pilkington";
    p.name = "Anthony";

    insert(&startPtr, p);
    printf("Age1:%d\n", p.age);

    struct person p2 = getStruct(&startPtr, 0);
    p2.age++;
    printf("Age2:%d\n", p2.age);

    struct person p3 = getStruct(&startPtr, 0);
    printf("Age3:%d\n", p3.age);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, my insert function and getStruct function are working correctly. But I cannot increment the age value. My output is:

```
Age1:22
Age2:23
Age3:22
```

I want to make the Age3 23. In insert function, I already allocate memory with malloc, but why can't I change the first value? How can I change this value without removing/adding the node from list?

I search the subject but I cannot find the answer that I want. So, If you can help me I appreciate that.

---EDIT-----
Sorry for not posting getStruct method, I am adding it below:

```
struct person getStruct(ListNodePtr *sPtr, int index) {
    ListNodePtr currentPtr;
    struct person c;

    int counter = 0;

    currentPtr = *sPtr;

    while (currentPtr != NULL) {
        if (counter == index) {
            c = currentPtr->data;
        }
        counter++;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
struct person p2 = getStruct(&startPtr, 0);
```

You return a `person` *by value*, which is to say you make a copy.  Then you modify the copy, not the original.  You'll need to do this instead:

```
struct person *p2 = getStruct(&startPtr, 0);
p2->age++;
printf("Age2:%d\n", p2->age);
```

That is, return a pointer, which you can use to modify what it points to.  This also requires a slight change to `getStruct()`, whose code you haven't posted.

Comment: Nice, to be precise the op need to return the address of the concerned structure from the `getStruct` function..

Comment: I added the function. Thanks for clear answer, so I think the `getStruct` function should return `struct person*`.

Comment: @pilkington: Yes, then you can simply `return &currentPtr->data`.

Comment: It worked with changing a few details in getStruct. Thanks again @JohnZwinck